# Retrive the original indexing after the merging of two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2` with the same column size, but `df1` has more rows than `df2`. I already knew that `df1` contains `df2`, so that their intersection will be `df2`.

My problem is that I want to merge these two data frames, the results I get will be equal as `df2`. But at the same time I need to know how the corresponding row order is in `df1`.

About duplicates: there are no same rows in `df2`, and a row in `df2` will be contained by one and only one row in `df1`.

For example,

```
>>df1
0   1   2   3
1   5   4   6
2   7   9   8
3   5   5   5
4   2   1   3
5   4   2   3 
6   10  5   6

>>df2
0   5   4   6
1   10  5   6
2   2   1   3
3   7   9   8
4   1   2   3
```

I want to have as result (The key is the order in df2 is unchanged, I need to know the corresponding row indexes of df1):

```
>>result

0   5   4   6  1
1   10  5   6  6 
2   2   1   3  4
3   7   9   8  2
4   1   2   3  0
```

I tried dataframe.merge and got a data frame same as df2, but I don't know how to get the row indexing of df1 (last column).

My original data frame sizes are quite big (~2,000,000), so the built-in loop function won't be the best choice as it is too expensive.

Comment: So, put another way, you want to know which row in df1 equals each row in df2?

Comment: before merging add columns with the index and name of the frame

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge`:

```
df2.merge(df1.reset_index(), on=list(df2.columns), how='left')
```

Output:

```
    1  2  3  0
0   5  4  6  1
1  10  5  6  6
2   2  1  3  4
3   7  9  8  2
4   1  2  3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the index first in df1 to get the index column, then merge and finally extract the index column.

```
df1.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df1.columns = ["index", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
df2.columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
result = df2.merge(on=["col2", "col3", "col4"])
df_index = result["index"]
```